# Find max value over the next 7 days for each group

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL table:

| id | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/01/2019 | 50 |
| 1 | 01/13/2019 | 24 |
| 1 | 01/19/2019 | 53 |
| 2 | 01/05/2019 | 50 |
| 2 | 01/11/2019 | 24 |
| 2 | 01/24/2019 | 53 |

I want to create a new column that computes that max value over the next 14 days grouped by id. If the difference between the date in the current row and the next is greater than 14, return None or Null.

The new table will be:

| id | date | value | max_14 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/01/2019 | 50 | 50 |
| 1 | 01/13/2019 | 24 | 53 |
| 1 | 01/19/2019 | 53 | None |
| 2 | 01/05/2019 | 50 | 50 |
| 2 | 01/11/2019 | 24 | 53 |
| 2 | 01/24/2019 | 53 | None |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a sub-query for this:

```
select t.*, (
    select max(value)
    from t as x
    where x.id = t.id
    and   x.date >= t.date
    and   x.date < dateadd(day, 14, t.date)
)
from t
```

Comment: This won't handle the logic of when there are no *other* rows in the next 14 days, return `'None'` (though I would suggest `NULL`).

Comment: a simple `having count(*) > 1` would fix it. Not sure why the OP wants a null in the last row per group.

Comment: I don't think it's just the last group, but they don't give any examples where a row that isn't the last fulfils the requirement. I agree, it is odd though.#

Comment: Apologies @SalmanA, null is the last is not required. thank you for your elegant answer :) thanks